# awk not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I have what I am assuming to be a very simple problem. I have used the following command in scripts many times before without issues.

```
display=/some/file/with/data
sed -i "s/$(more ${display} | grep 110 | gawk '{ print $3 }')/"replacestring"/g" ${display}
```

Never had an issue with this command.

I created a script that simplified everything that was needed and have the following code:

```
displayText=$(more ${display} | grep 110 | gawk '{ print $3 }')
```

I keep receiving

> line 2: syntax error: unexpected end of file.

I am very familiar with Linux so the problem has been quite irritating as the answer has escaped me. Please assist.

Comment: Hard to say not knowing your **display=/some/file/with/data** ... I'll hazard a guess and say it now contains something it didn't use to which breaks the number of apostrophes for awk?

Comment: Mixing sed, grep, awk, and more (?!) like this is a good way to invite trouble.  Don't let too many cooks in your kitchen at once.  AWK can do everything you're trying to do.

Comment: A sample of your input and desired output would be helpful.

Comment: If those are really backticks ('`') instead of single quotes (') around the gawk command, it's a wonder it ever worked.

Comment: I'm sorry but no-one who is `very familiar with Linux` would write that code.

Comment: Yes I know `awk` can do it with everything and yes those are supposed to be single quotes (I made an edit). Merely experimenting and trying new things and ran into this issue. this is by no means production code, merely learning.

Comment: Also, wouldn't you want to mix grep and awk for the performance benefits? Since grep is exceptionally faster for searching at patterns and then use either awk or sed to replace?

Comment: No, mixing grep and awk wouldn't provide any performance benefit.  The startup costs for starting a second program, setting up the pipeline, the pipeline latency and transfer speed and context switches would usually exceed any benefit.   One of the reasons Larry Wall wrote `perl` was to remove performance bottlenecks due to all the context switching between sh and grep and awk and sed, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you are using `more`.
You also have backquotes around the awk script where you should have single quotes.

```
displayText=$(cat ${display} | grep 110 | gawk '{ print $3 }')
```

You will be told that this is a useless-use-of-cat (the cat command isn't needed since grep can read a file).  You can just do:

```
displayText=$(grep 110 ${display} | gawk '{ print $3 }')
```

As awk can also search, this can be simplified further into:

```
displayText=$(gawk '/110/ {print $3}'  ${display})
```

Comment: No, there's no replacement.  That was part of his original code, but not part of his question.